# Android Things How to call WiFi settings from app

Tags: android, android-things

I am trying to open WiFi activity from my android App on Android Things preview 6 version. 
Below code works for mobile but gives error for Android Things  preview 6 on Raspberry Pi 3

> startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));

Error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.embdroid.android.homegatewayapp, PID: 11302
>                     android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default WiFi settings activity has been removed in recent previews. You can use the network manager APIs to programmatically connect to networks or use the default launcher which has a WiFi settings section.

Comment: Finally, I created my own WiFi Setup activity for Android Things but now I am not able to add or remove network through my app. may be due to this changes ==> Wi-Fi configuration lockdown: Any Wi-Fi configuration created by an active Device Owner can no longer be modified or deleted by the user if WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN is non-zero. The user can still create and modify their own Wi-Fi configurations. Active Device Owners have the privilege of editing or removing any Wi-Fi configurations, including those not created by them.

Comment: Did you set up a device owner? If you set up all WiFi through your app you should be able to control it.

Comment: No, My App is not device owner. How to setup app as device owner? And later I tested and found whatever wifi setup done by my App can be remove from same app.

Comment: As the OEM in this case, you should be able to do all of the Wi-Fi funneling through your app and thus be able to modify all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this sometime it needs complete path:

```
           Intent i = new Intent();
           i.setClassName("com.android.settings",
           "com.android.settings.wifi.Settings_Wifi_Settings");
            startActivity(i);
```

let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Nope, not working
Below is the error, seems like need to decleare in AndroidManifest.xml
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.embdroid.android.homegatewayapp, PID: 28348
                  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.settings/com.google.settings.WirelessSettings}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes, and result is same  and also declare Settings in Manifest
<activity android:name="com.android.Settings"/>
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.wifi.Settings_Wifi_Settings}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: is there something that I am missing or dont know about android things